# Python Sorting Pandas dataframe results in random results

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am observing some random sort results for a dataframe that I intend to sort by dates in ascending order. For multiple runs, most of the runs returns the correct results but for a small number of runs, it returns an incorrect results.

```
            records_df = records_df.groupby(['YEAR','QUARTER','SUPPLIER_ID']).TRANSACTION_DATES.agg({'TRANSACTION_DATES' : lambda x: list(x.unique())}).reset_index()
            # This now sorts in date order
            records_df.sort_values(by=['TRANSACTION_DATES'])
```

For most runs:
TRANSACTION_DATES: [05-Sep-17, 06-Sep-17, 07-Sep-17]

For some runs: Incorrect results is seen:

TRANSACTION_DATES: [06-Sep-17, 07-Sep-17, 05-Sep-17]

Why is that so since I am already enforcing a sort using sort_values?

Comment: There must be more to the code, because `.sort_values` has nothing random about it and should return the same sort order every run

Comment: there is nothing much going on. The last portion is to write to excel using                 records_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='SUMMARY', header=True, index=False, startrow=6,
                    columns=records_df.columns.values.tolist())

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you are using sort_values without assigning or using the inplace argument. This means that your sorted dataframe is just disappearing and is not stored anywhere.

So try:

```
records_df = records_df.sort_values(by=['TRANSACTION_DATES'])
```

or

```
records_df.sort_values(by=['TRANSACTION_DATES'], inplace=True)
```

For reference, the sort_values docs:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html

Comment: Hi tim654321, added the in_place=True property and it is still not working. The ascending sort is still happening at random and the result is non-deterministic. Was wondering if this is happening because the TRANSACTION_DATES  is of Type "object" and not datetime Type?

Comment: I wonder what type of object it is. Try type(records_df['TRANSACTION_DATES'][0]) to check the type of the objects in there. Strings and various types of date objects etc should still all have sorted in order.

Comment: Hi tim654321, the print output is <class 'list'>

Comment: So that means that your dates are nested inside a list in each element of your date series. Go back to how you created the data, and ensure that the dates you are loading are not stored within (likely single element) lists